# Sublime Text file_exclude_settings not excluding file from search results

Tags: sublimetext3

I have the file

> /Users/maxpleaner/Hover/website/ngapps/account/account.partials.js

that I want to exclude from my search results.

Present in the `.gitignore` is

> ngapps/**/*.partials.js

which I would like to ignore via Sublime settings also. But at minimum, being able to exclude all `.partials.js` files would do the trick.

I tried putting `"ngapps/**/*.partials.js"` and `*/partials.js` in my file_exclude_settings, but neither one of them actually works to exclude the file from the search results.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had it as `file_exclude_settings` but it's actually supposed to be `file_exclude_patterns`.

*facepalm!*